# Why multiple functions are allowing me to edit a pointer passed by value?

Tags: c++, pointers

As a beginner C++ coder, I am losing my head around pointers. I have correctly understood many things (and used them to implement different structures), but this "particular" situation is making me lose my head since Saturday.

If I pass a pointer by value (int* pointer), I am able to edit what it points to, but not the pointer (since it's a copy). And this correctly works. I am okay with that.

```
// pass a pointer by value (creating a copy)
void editPointerValue(int* pointer)
{

  int c = 200;
  int *p = &c;
  // has no effect. perfect!
  pointer = p;
}
```

if I call this function in my main, and print the pointer, it will stay the same. perfect.

**BUT if I call one of these functions BEFORE:**

```
// pass pointer to the pointer (allows pointer editing)
void editPointer(int** pointer)
{

  int a = 75;
  int *p = &a;
  *pointer = p;
}
// pass pointer as reference (allows pointer editing)
void editPointerReference(int*& pointer)
{

  int b = 100;
  int *p = &b;
  pointer = p;
}
```

Then, my pass-by-value function is **allowed to change the pointer too!**

what I mean is:

```
  int a = 0;
  int pointer = &p;
  // (doesn't do anything)
  editPointerValue(pointer);

  // (correct. prints 0)
  cout << *pointer << endl;


  // (pointer / sets 75)
  editPointer(&pointer);
        
  // (reference / sets 100)
  editPointerReference(pointer);
        
  // (by value / shouldn't set to 200. Like before)
  editPointerValue(pointer);

  cout << *pointer << endl;

  // should print 100, instead it prints 200.
```

I surrender. I don't know why calling another function before, changes the next one's behavior.

Comment: Turn on your warnings. You’re invoking ub.

Comment: FYI, both `editPointer` and `editPointerReference` change the caller's pointer to point to memory that is not valid after the return (pointers to `a` and `b` are only valid within the context of those functions).

Comment: @crashmstr that's true too, but if I print (in the main) the pointer after those functions, the printed values correspond to 75 and 100. So the pointer memory location still contains those numbers after the return... (?)

Comment: @Taekahn I have everything turned on. No warnings about that piece of code. *sad face*

Comment: Undefined behavior cannot be logically reasoned about. The compiler is allowed to exhibit any behavior. It can work every day of the week but Tuesday.

Comment: Anyway, by modifying those functions and avoiding pointing to invalid memory, made everything work as intended. Thank you both a lot. Didn't encounter UB before (didn't even know what it was). I truly expected some kind of error warning. 

Thanks again!

Comment: "i truly expected some kind of warning" https://godbolt.org/z/d9aPTTvEq lots of warnings.

Comment: Using VSCode it just doesn't say anything (about that part)... both in debug and normal terminal. I'll use this website you linked as a double check in the future!

Comment: This is one of those rare times I recommend c tutorials for c++ programmers.  Pointers are infrequently used in c++ but it's a good idea to understand what they are and how they work. Since you can't do much of anything in c w/o pointers, their study material goes into more detail with examples.

Comment: Looks like those warnings were added in GCC 12, which is pretty new https://godbolt.org/z/WvMdPj5Ms

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was invoking Undefined Behavior and it still compiled in weird ways. (with no warning whatsoever)